# How do i remove this error?

Tags: apex, unit-test, error

```java
@isTest
private class DummyTest {
    
    static final String NAMESPACE = PeopleCloudHelper.getPackageNamespace();
    
    static testmethod void testCombinedAllType() {
        System.runAs(DummyRecordCreator.platformUser) {
        PCAppSwitch__c pcAppCustomSetting = new PCAppSwitch__c();
            pcAppCustomSetting.Candidate_Record_Type_API_Name__c = [select Id, name, DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Contact' AND Name = 'Candidate'].DeveloperName;
            insert pcAppCustomSetting;    
        
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject` in line 3.

But if I remove this line 3, i.e. `static final String NAMESPACE = PeopleCloudHelper.getPackageNamespace();` and add it only in the test method as `String NAMESPACE = PeopleCloudHelper.getPackageNamespace();` where NAMESPACE is being used, the error is getting removed.

How do I remove this error without removing line 3?

I tried to add this after line 2 as well, but didn't work.

```
@testSetup static void setup() {
            
    PCAppSwitch__c pcAppCustomSetting = new PCAppSwitch__c();
    pcAppCustomSetting.Candidate_Record_Type_API_Name__c = [select Id,name,DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Contact' AND Name = 'Candidate'].DeveloperName;
    insert pcAppCustomSetting;    
}
```

The method on line 3 is:

```
public static String getPackageNamespace(){
    String placementName=Schema.SObjectType.Placement__c.getName();
    String namespace ='';
    //system.debug('Placement__c name:'+placementName);
    if(placementName.indexOf('__') != placementName.lastIndexOf('__')){
          namespace = placementName.split('__')[0]+'__';
    }
    //if(placementName.contains('PeopleCloud1__'))
    //  namespace='PeopleCloud1__';
    return namespace;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that is causing the error? From the error message it looks more like something that would be caused by assigning the query result to the PCAppSwitch__c.. (and nothing returned in the query). Can you see that in the debug logs?

Comment: @GuyClairbois yes , because PeopleCloudHelper.getPackageNamespace() is using the data from PCAppSwitch__c